# How could javafx.scene.web.WebEngine login a website with post method

Tags: java, web, javafx

I want to user JavaFX access a website and login automatically. But some websites don't support `GET` method to login. How to set `POST` parameters?

Comment: What websites? What have you tried? Please give us some code and explain where this code works and where not. Do you know why it didn't work and don't know how to prevent it? A little bit more info would be really helpful...